# The most efficient way to determine the presence of repeated values in a 2D array, arranged like a table (with some starting ideas)

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am switching the tags for this question as I don't believe it is a C# .NET specific question, and more so a mathematical/algorithms one. Say I have an 2D array of ints, like below:

```
 0 | 1 | 2
---+---+---
 0 | 1 | 0  
---+---+---
 1 | 0 | 0
```

These could be stored in a different data structure if this would allow a faster solution to the problem. **The problem being** how to detect (and find the locations of) equal integer values stored adjacently (allowing for diagonals) (and not accounting for "wrapping around" adjacency, for example a corner piece should only need to be compared with 3 other values... that is unless there is a better solution to storing the data).

My first (and I am sure naive) approach would be a 2D array (implemented as a jagged array or just indexed like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)) in which I store the integer values. I have no need for any sort property besides just whether or not values are equal (i.e. no need for `>`, `<`, etc). I could then do an `N^8` `(not sure if this is the correct time analysis for this situation but it was my best try)`traversal of all N locations in the array, and 8 checks maximum (if not on the edge) per iteration. I think there may be a better way to do this, however. Especially as this approach is very time consuming.

One idea I had is to modify the data structure so that every item has a flag (included in each structure in the array [so not just an array of ints]) of whether it is the same as any adjacent value. This would slow down my insertion and building processes, but may `(??)` speed up the process of finding pairs in the table. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show how you're currently doing it.

Comment: Is it always 3x3?

Comment: _"I was thinking about maybe regex?"_ **-** Please don't think that.

Comment: What is the range of allowed values? Are they always non-negative int? Is there a max value?

Comment: I agree 100% with @maccettura.  Regular expressions are for pattern matching on strings, not for finding duplicate integer values in an array.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "twice in a row"  clearly the example you give doesn't have duplicates 1's in the same row, but instead column.  What if there are duplicates at position (1,1) and (2,2)  would that be "in a row".

Comment: Yes, can you confirm "twice in a row" means directly consecutive?  If so, once you've extracted all the values for a given row or column, essentially it's a problem of finding the subsequence [1,1] within it. .NET doesn't really have any built-in way of doing that, though you could convert to a string and look for "11" in the output easily enough. There are other posts on SO discussing the more general problem of finding subsequences. And does "any direction" include diagonal?

Comment: Are you just looking for a `true` or `false` result if any value occurs more than once in succession? Or do you need some indicator of the location of the values? When you say any direction, do you mean diagonally as well, like Tic-Tac-Toe?

Comment: Should matches which require wrapping past edges count (e.g. do the 0 in the first and last column of the 2nd row count as adjacent)?

Comment: not in my case @Makyen, I will add that to the question to make it more clear

Comment: I'd suggest adding what you expect as output to make it more clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to just traverse the rows and check if the value in the current cell matches one of it's neighbors. If you always move from left to right and top to bottom, then you only need to check a maximum of 4 other cells: the cell to the right and the three cells below (prev column, this column, and next column). As soon as you find a match, you return true. If no matches are found, return false:

```
private static bool HasRepeatingItem(int[][] board)
{
    if (board == null) return false;

    for (int row = 0; row < board.Length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].Length; col++)
        {
            var thisValue = board[row][col];

            // If there's another column, check for horizontal match
            if (col < board[row].Length - 1 && thisValue == board[row][col + 1])
                return true;

            // If there's a row below, check for matches
            if (row < board.Length - 1)
            {
                // Check directly below for vertical match
                if (thisValue == board[row + 1][col]) return true;

                // Check below left for horizontal match
                if (col > 0 && thisValue == board[row + 1][col - 1]) return true;

                // Check below right for horizontal match
                if (col < board[row].Length - 1 && thisValue == board[row + 1][col + 1]) 
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start brute force with the first cell (index), check against all neighboring cells. Go to the next cell, check against neighboring cells, then the next, and so on.

When you get that working, you'll probably get some ideas for improving it. Eventually you will understand the process and can advance to better algorithms.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any theoretically possible way to evaluate this without just brute forcing (and accounting for edges)?

Comment: Sure there are lots of theory on arrays and grids, in general. If you do not provide specifics, it's difficult to be specific on this side too, here's a couple of thoughts... expand rows and columns as numbers populate it (think dynamic edges). Build the grid as a list of known three-in-a-row objects, instead of a 2D grid that has to be parsed (think dynamic grid like tree).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check each cell for a match by checking all surrounding cells (if they exist) for a total of 8 checks per cell. This is the basic idea of what you will want to do. I wrote the first condition to give you the idea.

```
bool checkBoard(int[,] boardArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.GetLength(0); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardArray.GetLength(1); j++) {
            // Above
            if ((j+1) < boardArray.GetLength(1) && boardArray[i][j] == boardArray[i][j+1])
                return true;
            // Above Right
            if ()
                return true;
            // Right
            if ()
                return true;
            // Below Right
            if ()
                return true;
            // Below
            if ()
                return true;
            // Below Left
            if ()
                return true;
            // Left
            if ()
                return true;
            // Above Left
            if ()
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the question (without any further constraints), the following straightforward solution should give what you need:

```
// Pseudo-code. Did not test it.
public static bool foundSameValuesInARow(int[,] board) { // board: NxN array. We assume it's a square array.
    int N = board.getLength(0);
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<N-1;j++) {
            if(board[i,j] == board[i+1,j] || board[i,j] == board[i,j+1]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<N-1;k++) {
        if(board[k, N-1] == board[k+1,N-1] || board[N-1,k] == board[N-1,k+1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It was really meant to be a pseudo code to illustrate the simple algorithm. Thanks for finding the typos. (in real code, you'll really need to check if board is null, etc., which obscures the essence of the answer.)